# Git is failing at merge. It is deleting files that should not

Tags: git, github, command-line

When I run `git merge master` this is what I get:

```
➜  billing git:(issue-103) git merge master                                                 
Auto-merging src/locales/en/translation.json
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/locales/en/translation.json
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/main.scss
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_table.scss
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_modal.scss deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_modal.scss left in tree.
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_itemsTable.scss
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_filtersBar.scss deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/scss/blocks/_filtersBar.scss left in tree.
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/reducers/index.js
Auto-merging src/client/pages/Shipments/index.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/client/pages/Shipments/index.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GraphQLQuery.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetShipmentsAddresses.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetShipments.js deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetShipments.js left in tree.
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetAllShipmentTypes.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetAllShipmentStatuses.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/containers/GetAllCouriers.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/constants/ActionTypes.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/actions/shipments.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/actions/index.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/TableToolbarComp.js deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/TableToolbarComp.js left in tree.
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/TableItemsHeaders.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/TableItemsHeader.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/TableHeaders.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/TableExpandedRowWrapper.js deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/TableExpandedRowWrapper.js left in tree.
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/TableExpandedRow.js
Removing src/client/pages/Shipments/TableEmptyState.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/ShipmentsTable.js deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/ShipmentsTable.js left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): src/client/pages/Shipments/FiltersModal.js deleted in master and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of src/client/pages/Shipments/FiltersModal.js left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

As you see, it is deleting many files I need which I just commited before merging master with my branch `issue-30`.

The curious part is that if I go to `master`, the `shipments` folder which is where I am developing some components, is empty.

So all of the files that says `Removing` shouldn't be removed.

So, what could be causing the deletion of those files?

Comment: Look in the history of master. There will be deletions of `src/client/pages/Shipments/*`. These deletions are being merged into your branch.